# Does filing my CV now at careers still keep it in draft stage?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I did search.

I'd like to take advantage of the three year promo, it looks like a great deal considering how well SO itself has done.

I'm not quite finished working on my CV. It will be a week or two (at least) until its ready.

If I pay now and file, will my CV still remain unpublished and in draft stage?

I've been an independent contractor for 5+ years, it takes a while to summarize and document that experience (for the morbidly curious)

**Edit**:

Please close this as its no longer relevant.

Comment: I'm in the same position. Ready to pay. Not ready to post.

Comment: @mmyers: This is also a temporal question, its usefulness expires in less than a month.. just felt like CW was the way to go.

Comment: Closing as "no longer relevant" is the way to go after it expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy the service now, and edit your CV before making it available to employers and publishing it publicly. You can even reserve your public URL before publishing.

Answer (score 1):

Paying for the service is not the same action as filing the CV. You can pay for the service and not use it if you desire it. I can confirm this, having signed up yesterday before actually finishing and filing my CV.