# Careers feature request: make the workflow more clear, put people at ease

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Careers is special, as has been discussed a few times on the podcast, in that people pay for certain aspects of it. Combined with the fact that we are talking about something that is much more personal (**my** CV, **my** career, recruiters, etc) it seems important to put the user at ease as much as possible.

The main thing that seems to be missing are clear and visible descriptions of what **will** happen if I take certain steps in the careers workflow. For example, from the website it is unclear whether I can "File" my CV without actually making it visible to recruiters. Many would like to take advantage of the special offers but may not yet be ready to submit a CV to recruiters (either because it is not done or because they are not looking).

Some [existing meta questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28180/does-filing-my-cv-now-at-careers-still-keep-it-in-draft-stage) seem to indicate that "Filing" is not automatically "making available to recruiters" but this remains unclear from the careers UI itself.

Reducing anxiety should surely be one of the maxims of web (or any) development.

Answer (score 2):

This is a semi-dupe as others have brought up the confusion between "filing" and "publishing", but it bears repeating, because right now it is not very clear what the ramifications are for performing each action. e.g. will recruiters still be able to see a "published" resume even if it is not "filed"? What if they match the "company blacklist" (still unimplemented, so it is unknown how that will work exactly)? Does everyone have to have the precise URL of a "published" resume in order to see it, or will there be a catalog somewhere?

I wouldn't have created a resume at all if it weren't for the (now-expired) 3-year beta offer, because these options were so confusing. So I settled for filing (there are no recruiters yet, so this *seems* safe), but not publishing so that others can't go look at my details (as my careers URL is pretty easy to guess).

Comment: Agreed that this issue has been discussed before on meta (see my link for example) but I did not yet see it as a concrete feature request.